# Transparent to color gradient CSS issue

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I've created a gradient which goes from transparent to white using this CSS:

```
linear-gradient(to right, transparent, white)
```

Also see: http://jsfiddle.net/fs8gpha2/

This is all working fine in Chrome, but in both Safari and Firefox the center of the gradient is grey. Is there any way to work around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
body {
    background: #000;
}

div {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgb(255, 255, 255));
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Here is the [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fs8gpha2/3/)

Comment: I apparently had to wait for 5 minutes before I was allowed to accept an answer. Done now :)

Answer (score 2):

This is would be a cross-browser solution (I updated the jsfiddle):

http://jsfiddle.net/fs8gpha2/4/

```
div { 
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), to(rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1));
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1));
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1));
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1));
background: linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1));
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); width:100%; height:100px; }
```

Cheers